# How to distinguish a vyatta router and firewalls are on a VLAN

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using URL SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans.json. What datatype do I specify in the mask to  get information on the firewall device and whether the VLAN is associated with a Vyatta? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the firewall information use the datatype [networkVlanFirewall](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/#networkvlanfirewall).

To know which gateway is associated to the vlan e.g. Vyatta, use the following mask:

```
mask[attachedNetworkGateway[members[hardware[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystem[softwareLicense[softwareDescription[manufacturer]]]]]]]
```

To get all this information use the below rest api call:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[networkVlanFirewall[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName],attachedNetworkGateway[members[hardware[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystem[softwareLicense[softwareDescription[manufacturer]]]]]]]
```